# How can I save state of component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular7

I'm looking at saving the state of a data table that I'm using in Angular 7 & Typescript.

The functionality is similar to saving state like in a browser tab.

So on redirection to another component, If I go back to the component with the data table, how can I save the state let's say if I'm using a filter?

Comment: Common approach would be to store it either in a service or in a local storage (if it's not sensitive)

Comment: The use of `RouteReuseStrategy` may be helpful (see https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy)

Comment: This may be a similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103263/angular-save-restore-component-state but I found these answers to be more succinct and therefore the up vote of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a state management library like https://ngrx.io/guide/store or use localstorage to save and fetch the filters.

Answer (score 0):

1 method would be to store the state in the local storage. So when you return back to the original page you can query to see if the item exists in the local storage if it does then reinitialise.

let data = {};
localStorage.setItem('settings', data);

this is not an effective way just for learning purpose its fine

Answer (score 0):

1. Local storage
2. ngrx/Store
3. Subject, or BehaviorSubject

The last option is two directional service, the best option would be probably Store.